# Keeping track of url while redirecting using threading with Selenium in python

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium, redirect, httplib

I have a url which has a chain of redirection, upto 3 i.e. it leads to another url and then that leads to another one until it happens thrice.

I want to close the browser as soon as last page **begins Loading**. I know that my url has been reached when the domain is changed to some specific url. I am trying to achieve this by using `driver.current_url` with **threading**.

I have implemented the threading class as:

```
class driverThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, driver):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.driver = driver;
    def run(self):
        print "Initiated thread: " + str(self.threadID);
        while True:

            #Here is the problem
            lk=str(self.driver.current_url);


            try:
                if lk.find('myhostname.com',lk.index('://')+2,lk.index('/',lk.index('://')+4))>=0:
                    sleep(1);
                else:
                    #quits the driver once the link has successfully redirected to destination url
                    print "VISITED";
                    self.driver.quit();
                    break;
            except ValueError:
                sleep(1);
                pass;
```

calling the same as:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options);
driverTh = driverThread(id,driver)
driverTh.start();
driver.get(link)
driverTh.join();
```

The problem is with line `lk=str(self.driver.current_url)`. when I run this script I get into an error stating `CannotSendRequest` which I know is due to issue with http lib. According to me it happens because my thread keeps on checking `driver.current_url` which would update when `driver.get(link)` is called. No sooner that the get function is called the thread gives the error `CannotSendRequest` mostly because it is getting the link now.

Comment: So you can put in `try: except`

Comment: Then everytime it goes into the EXCEPT and I am unable to get the url

Comment: It's look like it never run `driver.get(link)` because it runs your endless Thread. And error cached because there's no `current_url` (didn't get yet).